# how to copy SSL certificate to another server via rsync

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, rsync

My setup consists of 2 servers - one for mailhost and other for webhost. As webhost has SSL certificates I need those to the mailhost server also (same domain).

Is there a way to safely copy certificate files from local webhost server to local mailhost server using rsync or any other way? And by doing so keeping the keys safe and accessible for dovecot.

I have tried giving sudo privileges to rsync on both ends (sudoers file also modified but still saying "no tty present and no askpass program specified"), also using ssh key but still no success.

What I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you generally shouldn't use the same certificate for both the web and mail servers. The basic setup is that the web server should have a cert for www.whatever.com with whatever.com as an alternate name (or maybe the reverse), and the mail server will have a cert for something like mail.whatever.com, or whatever its host name is. Note that the mail server's cert should be for its hostname, *not* the domain it serves for. It's entirely normal to have a mail server that isn't even under the same top-level domain as the domain it's serving for -- if there's an MX record in the DNS that says mail for whatever.com should go to someserver.isp.net, that's completely normal, and the mail server needs a cert for someserver.isp.net, *not* whatever.com.

Second, it sounds like you're trying to over-automate this. If you did need the same cert on multiple computers, you should generally copy it manually between the servers (using e.g. `scp` between unprivileged accounts), and then install it manually on each server. On the other hand, if you're using an automated cert generation system like [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org)'s, you're probably better off generating independent certs on each server.

There's a significant security risk with allowing automated privilege escalation, like allowing `rsync` to run as root via sudo. Unless you're very careful, anyone with any access to the system could take advantage of this to e.g. modify any file they want (including /etc/sudoers) simply by doing it with rsync! Similarly, allowing one server to remote into another as root means anyone who can take over one server automatically gets full control of the other. This is dangerous! Don't do it unless you really need to, and in that case you need to really really understand exactly what you're doing.

Comment: As I have only 1 IP address and router is doing the port forwarding then based on your answer I think I'm going to make a script that helps lets encyrpt certbot to automatically make the SSL renewal (make the required file to confirm webpage ownership). 

Giving the rsync sudo privileges is a security risk I knew but I thought that there may be a way somehow to automate its renewal safely.

Comment: There is a situation I am in I dont think the above will work, and hence I need to sync it... I have a "failover" website on a different server. If the main website goes down, our DNS provider switches the domain to a new server. We sync. the site daily, including SSL. For some reason the ssl.cert is not syncing, so Apache goes down. We do not want to manually do this every time a new SSL is issues, its supposed to be an automated sync. And we cannot set LetsEncrypt to auto renew as the public domain dos not point to this server. If we can just sync. the ssl it all works fine.

Comment: @LaurenceCope Without more info about your setup and how you're syncing it's hard to respond in detail. It's difficult to securely allow synchronization of the cert *and private key*, but in your situation that may not be necessary. One option is to do the initial cert+key sync manually, then just reuse the private key when renewing (e.g. `certbot --reuse-key` or similar), and have the script sync *just the public cert* (not the private key), and then have the sync script update just the cert (leaving the same private key) on the failover server.

Comment: I was just pointing out a situation that could not use your methods and needed to auto sync. Your comment about reusing the key is interesting though, didn’t know about that. So maybe there are other ways around it. Although we use a server management system (virtualmin) which has the auto renewal built in do not sure if I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

rsync works like this: `rsync -P from_host_user@from_host_ip:path1 to_host_user@to_host_ip:path2`

This logs in to the ssh port on from_host_ip with from_host_user, copy the file from path1, logs into to_host_ip with to_host_user and puts the file on path2

Comment: I knew how rsync works but it didn't allow copying SSL cert files because they were protected.

Comment: then you either need to login as root (for the from_user) or login as a different user first and change the permission with sudo (i.e ``` sudo chmod +r path_to_ssl_file ```